# Kali linux installation graphics messed up

Tags: kali-linux, display

I made a Kali linux installation medium using rufus, and live works only in forensic mode. And all other modes like install isn't working.

It has to be UEFI:

[image: This is what happens, every time]

And his happens. I tried DD and iso, both the same result.

edit:

lspci output:

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)

00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: Isn't forensic mode the only reason Kali exists?

Comment: Please extend your question with your /var/log/Xorg.0.log and with your lspci output.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is independent from the method, how do you create your installation medium.

Your Kali is clearly installable and it boots.

The problem is with your graphics driver.

A workaround is to install it in VESA modus. With it, you lose 3d acceleration and your image quality won't be the best, but at least it will work.

A `vga=ask` will help a lot. You might also try to switch to a character console (alt-ctrl-f1), and check your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Check, which driver is it trying to use and use a different one.

Comment: vga=ask won't change anything...
and how do i check /var/log/Xorg.0.log
and where do i have to switch to a character console

Sorry for these many questions...

Comment: Aaaaand how do i install in VESA mode? 'cause i think i am booting in VESA modus...

Comment: Google. And never use "I" in lowercase any more.

Comment: I didn't found anything on Google, would be nice, if you would help me...